# How to get average session duration for a specific user in flurry

Tags: unity-game-engine, flurry

I am using flurry analytics in my unity game .
In flurry, we are getting average session duration for a specific date or date range. We want to get session duration for all users individually. i.e. assume 10 users played our game today and total no of  session is 25. I like to get session duration for all 25 sessions separately along with user id. is this possible? If yes, can you please share some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get individual session times for each user through Flurry. Flurry session data is geared towards aggregating the session length, to give you an overall idea of how long users are spending in the app, not to drill down to specific user times. The closest metric to what you are describing is The session length distribution chart on the Usage>Session Length page, which distributes the sessions into buckets based on length, so you can see how many sessions of a given range occurred.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Any other possible way to get specific users session details.

Comment: @Sabs-Flurry has one default  function as LogUserID (UserID) . So that you can assign ID for every user.From that user id we can track the details of the individual user through event logs